# Formatting date output from database?

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime

If I get the value using `ExecuteScalar()` method, which consist only of `DATE` data type, it ended up with something like:

```
12-14-14 12:00:00 AM
02-27-14 12:00:00 AM
05-21-14 12:00:00 AM
```

What I want for an output is this format `mm-dd-yy`, which is:

```
12-14-14
02-27-14
05-21-14
```

Been searching a lot last night and have not found an answer yet.

How can I format the result like `mm-dd-yy`?

Comment: Please show your actual code.  It will answer many questions for us. For example, the return type you are expecting.

Comment: [msdn string format for dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). enjoy

Comment: @KirkWoll - I'm using a mySQL Query which takes the whole row of data then put it to a ListView control.

Comment: @cboy123 then post your code, that reads it into a listview if you want people to help you otherwise we can only guess on what you're doing and give you the closer option. **There is an EDIT link below your question you can use for that.**

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to format the output, use something like:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("02-27-14 12:00:00 AM");
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MM-dd-yy"));
// Output: 02-27-14
```